# Move metabox up on side WordPress Post admin

Tags: metabox

I have the following PHP code for WordPress. I'm placing it in my functions.php file. It adds the metabox on the bottom right side for my Post pages in the admin area. Is there a way for me to get it to the top the other meta boxes (categories, tags, featured image, etc.). I have a Yoast SEO metabox at the top, so they somehow figured out how to do it. I've worked with the priority with default, core, high, low, but no luck - it's always on the bottom. Thanks in advance!

```
// Function to display and edit the custom published date field in the post editor
function custom_published_date_field() {
    global $post;

    // Get the custom published date value
    $custom_published_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_published_date', true);

    // If the custom date is not set, use the actual published date
    if (empty($custom_published_date)) {
        $post_date = get_the_date('F j, Y', $post->ID); // Get the published date of the post in the desired format
        $custom_published_date = date('F j, Y', strtotime($post_date));
    }

    // Output the field in the post editor
    echo '<label for="custom-published-date">Custom Published Date:</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="custom-published-date" name="custom_published_date" value="' . esc_attr($custom_published_date) . '" class="widefat" />';

    // Add nonce for security
    wp_nonce_field('custom_published_date_nonce', 'custom_published_date_nonce');
}



// Save the custom published date when the post is saved
function save_custom_published_date($post_id) {
    // Check if this is an autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    // Check if the user has permission to edit the post
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return;

    // Verify the nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['custom_published_date_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_published_date_nonce'], 'custom_published_date_nonce')) return;

    // Save the custom published date
    if (isset($_POST['custom_published_date'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_published_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_published_date']));
    }
}

// Hook the custom field into the post editor
function add_custom_published_date_field() {
    add_meta_box('custom-published-date', 'Custom Published Date', 'custom_published_date_field', 'post', 'side', 'high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_published_date_field');
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_published_date');
```